# Is it safe to traverse a container during std::remove_if execution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

Suppose I want to remove the *unique* elements from an `std::vector` (not get rid of the duplicates, but retain only the elements that occur at least 2 times) and I want to achieve that in a pretty inefficient way - by calling `std::count` while `std::remove_if`ing. Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6};

    auto to_remove = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&vec](int n) {
        return std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), n) == 1;
    });

    vec.erase(to_remove, vec.end());

    for (int i : vec) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

From [reference on `std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) we know that the elements beginning from `to_remove` have *unspecified* values, but I wonder how unspecified they can really be.

To explain my concern a little further - we can see that the elements that should be removed are `1`, `3`, `5` and `7` - the only unique values. `std::remove_if` will move the `1` to the end but there is no guarantee that there will be a value `1` at the end after said operation. Can this be (due to that value being *unspecified*) that it will turn into `3` and make the `std::count` call return a count of (for example) **2** for the later encountered value `3`?

Essentially my question is - is this guaranteed to work, and by *work* I mean to inefficiently erase unique elements from an `std::vector`?

I am interested in both language-lawyer answer (which could be "*the standard says that this situation is possible, you should avoid it*") and in-practice answer (which could be "*the standard says that this situation is possible, but realistically there is no way of this value ending up as a completely differeny one, for example `3`*").

Comment: I understand from the reference that you could get wrong results. E.g. [1, 2, 1, 3] -> [1, 1, 3, 3] after 2 is removed (because 3 is move assigned to position 2 and the value of position 3 after move assignment is not defined). Now 3 is not unique and wouldn't be removed in the next step.

Comment: @ThomasSablik that's my suspicion also, but I'd love to have someone logically prove this. Cppreference is great, but it's just a wiki. An example where it fails would be stellar - with details regarding compiler and compiler flags.

Comment: @Fureeish Your input data has acccording to me four (not three) unique values that are to be removed. 1, 3, *5*, and 7.

Comment: @BoR my mistake, edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the predicate returns `true` the first time, there will be one unspecified value in the range.   That means any subsequent calls of the predicate will count an unspecified value.  The count is therefore potentially incorrect, and you may either leave values unaffected that you intend to be discarded, or discard values that should be retained.

You could modify the predicate so it keeps a count of how many times it has returned true, and reduce the range accordingly.  For example;

```
std::size_t count = 0;
auto to_remove = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&vec, &count](int n)
{
    bool once = (std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end() - count, n) == 1);
    if (once) ++count;
    return once;
 });
```

Subtracting an integral value from a vector's end iterator is safe, but that isn't necessarily true for other containers.

Comment: I think the question boils down to what exactly *unspecified* means. Given the fact that it technically *can* be anything, I am convinced that this is unsafe. Thank you.

Comment: @Fureeish the standard says "unspecified ... because the algorithms can eliminate elements by moving from elements that were originally in that range". so unspecified means the result of moving a value of the container. using `int` is most definately unsafe because the previous value is kept.

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstood how `std::remove_if` works. The to-be-removed values are not necessarily shifted to the end. See:

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

This is the only guarantee for the state of the range. According to my knowledge, it's not forbidden to shift all values around and it would still satisfy the complexity. So it might be possible that some compilers shift the unwanted values to the end but that would be just extra unnecessary work.

An example of possible implementation of removing odd numbers from `1 2 3 4 8 5`:

```
   v               - read position
   1 2 3 4 8 5     - X will denotes shifted from value = unspecified
   ^               - write position
     v          
   1 2 3 4 8 5     1 is odd, ++read
   ^
       v
   2 X 3 4 8 5     2 is even, *write=move(*read), ++both
     ^   
         v
   2 X 3 4 8 5     3 is odd, ++read
     ^
           v
   2 4 3 X 8 5     4 is even, *write=move(*read), ++both
       ^
             v
   2 4 8 X X 5     8 is even, *write=move(*read), ++both
         ^

   2 4 8 X X 5     5 is odd, ++read
         ^         - this points to the new end.
```

So, in general, you cannot rely on `count` returning any meaningful values. Since in the case that move==copy (as is for `ints`) the resulting array is `2 4 8|4 8 5`. Which has incorrect count both for the odd and even numbers. In case of `std::unique_ptr` the `X==nullptr` and thus the count for `nullptr` and removed values might be wrong. Other remaining values should not be left in the end part of the array as there were no copies done.

Note that the values are not unspecified as in you cannot know them. They are exactly the results of move assignments which might leave the value in unspecified state. If it specified the state of the moved-from variables ( as`std::unique_ptr` does) then they would be known. E.g. if `move==swap` then the range will be permuted only.

Comment: Your cited paragraph does not specify which elements are shifted where - it only specifies the outcome, but good catch that I incorrectly assumed (like you just now :> ) that the to-be-removed ones will be shifted.

Comment: @Fureeish Yes, I restated the answer perhaps in more correct way.

Answer (score 2):

I added some outputs:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6};

    auto to_remove = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&vec](int n) {

        std::cout << "number " << n << ": ";
        for (auto i : vec) std::cout << i << ' ';
        auto c = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), n);
        std::cout << ", count: " << c << std::endl;
        return c == 1;
    });

    vec.erase(to_remove, vec.end());

    for (int i : vec) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

and got

```
number 1: 1 2 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 1
number 2: 1 2 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 2
number 6: 2 2 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 3
number 3: 2 6 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 1
number 6: 2 6 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 4
number 2: 2 6 6 3 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 2
number 7: 2 6 6 2 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 1
number 4: 2 6 6 2 6 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 2
number 4: 2 6 6 2 4 2 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 3
number 5: 2 6 6 2 4 4 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 1
number 6: 2 6 6 2 4 4 7 4 4 5 6 , count: 3
2 6 6 2 4 4 6
```

As you can see the counts can be wrong. I'm not able to create an example for your special case but as a rule you have to worry about wrong results.

First the number 4 is counted twice and in the next step the number 4 is counted thrice. The counts are wrong and you can't rely on them.

Comment: Any reason for using mutual exclusions here?

Comment: @Fureeish No, I removed it